# canvas.toDataURL() seems truncated

Tags: javascript, canvas, base64

I am trying to encode a .png to base64 in javascript:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "img.png";
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
context.getImageData(0, 0, 224 , 224);
var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
```

And If I put an alert(base64.length);
I get 1594...even If I am not an expert in base64 encoding I have the feeling that It is supposed to be much more longer for a 224 x 224 image.
If someone can help me to understand better how It works and how I could solve the problem It would be great.

Also, I can't display the file with `window.open(base64)`, it returns a blank image.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `toDataURL()` returns the canvas data in PNG format, which supports excellent lossless compression. 1KB or so isn't unheard of for a 224x224 image, especially if it's a more simplistic image. For comparison, if you run the original `img.png` file through a PNG compressor (tinypng.com or similar will do this), what's the compressed file size?

Comment: I am in anycase around 20 KB ... And when I use an online base64 converter I get a really long string which is closer to 10 KB than 1KB

Comment: You are indeed creating 300px × 150px transparent images here: You have to wait for your image has loaded before being able to draw it (your console should have said you something about it) and set your canvas `.width` and `.height` to the ones of your image once it has loaded. For next time, as basic debugging tips, you could have guessed what was wrong by displaying these exported images, and appending your canvas on the doc.

Comment: Thank you! You solved my issue